# Do i need to know the variables before launching a campain in voximplant kit?

Tags: voximplant

I need to know the variables involved in a campaign before appending contacts to it, do I?
https://voximplant.com/kit/docs/references/kit/campaigns#appendtocampaign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to, strings should match the initial campaign start (you can use initCampaign for it https://voximplant.com/kit/docs/references/kit/campaigns#initcampaign) because appendtocampaing only works for existing campaigns